# Row sum, column sum & diagonal sum of a matrix using list comprehension. Also get rid of error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matrix, sum, list-comprehension

I want to do column sum using List comprehension. Below is my code and corresponding error. If someone can help me mitigate the problem, would be great. I just want to use List comprehension only, don't want to use 'zip' function.

Code:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint
r=int(input('Enter number of rows   :'))
c=int(input('Enter number of columns:'))
l=[[randint(1,50) for i in range(r)] for j in range(c)]
print('The 2D Matrix is: ')
pprint(l)
lr_sum = [sum(l[i]) for i in range(r)] 
print('Row Sum:    ', lr_sum)
lc_sum=[[sum(l[j][i]) for i in range(r)] for j in range(c)]
print('Column sum: ', lc_sum)
```

Output:

```py
Enter number of rows   :5
Enter number of columns:5
The 2D Matrix is: 
[[27, 3, 1, 28, 9],
 [18, 20, 9, 50, 48],
 [2, 44, 45, 14, 39],
 [48, 12, 2, 38, 39],
 [2, 37, 46, 26, 23]]
Row Sum:     [68, 145, 144, 139, 134]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "19.py", line 10, in <module>
    lc_sum=[[sum(l[j][i]) for i in range(r)] for j in range(c)]
  File "19.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    lc_sum=[[sum(l[j][i]) for i in range(r)] for j in range(c)]
  File "19.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    lc_sum=[[sum(l[j][i]) for i in range(r)] for j in range(c)]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Thanks,
Sudip Ray
Python - Beginner

Comment: Thanks for correction. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a simple mistake in your `lc_sum` definition. `l[j][i]` refers to a single (integer) value of your matrix. You cannot sum over a single value. Try it out yourself. E.g. `sum(1)` raises the same `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

In order for your code to work, you need to sum over the whole nested list comprehension:

```
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint


r = int(input('Enter number of rows   :'))
c = int(input('Enter number of columns:'))
l = [[randint(1, 50) for i in range(r)] for j in range(c)]
print('The 2D Matrix is: ')
pprint(l)
lr_sum = [sum(l[i]) for i in range(r)] 
print('Row Sum:    ', lr_sum)
lc_sum = [sum([l[j][i] for i in range(r)]) for j in range(c)]
print('Column sum: ', lc_sum)
```

Be aware however, that this is not the correct way to calculate the column sums. For the correct calculation, you also need to swap your list comprehensions:

```
lc_sum = [sum([l[j][i] for j in range(c)]) for i in range(r)]
```

Comment: I found workaround. I transposed the matrix and did the row sum. I got the desired result; but I was expecting a way around the column sum the way it did in row sum. Do you have any other clue?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking and which way you are referring to. The one I explained in my answer? If you are generelly interested in a more pythonic way of calculating the row and collumn sums, then yes, there are better ways to do that.

Comment: I got the column sum like this:l_new=[[l[j][i] for j in range(c)] for i in range(r)]
lc_sum = [sum(l_new[i]) for i in range(c)]
print(lc_sum)

Comment: can you help me with the code of column sum using list comprehension. I am stuck basically. My workaround unnecessarily created new matrix with interchanging rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks, I got it without transposing the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
##################################################################################

from pprint import pprint
from random import randint
r=int(input('Enter number of rows   :'))
c=int(input('Enter number of columns:'))
#l=[[int(input('Enter the numbers: ')) for j in range(c)] for i in range(r)]
l=[[randint(1,50) for j in range(c)] for i in range(r)]
print('The 2D Matrix is: ')
pprint(l)

##################################################################################

if(r!=c):
    lr_sum = [sum(l[i]) for i in range(r)]
    print('Row Sum             :', lr_sum)
    lc_sum=[sum(l[j][i] for j in range(r)) for i in range(c)]
    print('Column sum          :', lc_sum)
    print('Please make sure that matrix is square')
    print('The diagonal sums are not possible')
     ##################################################################################

else:

    lr_sum = [sum(l[i]) for i in range(r)]
    print('Row Sum             :', lr_sum)
    lc_sum=[sum(l[j][i] for j in range(r)) for i in range(c)]
    print('Column sum          :', lc_sum)
    ld1_sum=[sum(l[i][j] for i in range(r) for j in range(c) if i==j)]
    ld2_sum=[sum(l[i][j] for i in range(r) for j in range(c-1,-1,-1) if (i+j==r-1))]
    print('Forward Diagonal sum:',ld1_sum)
    print('Reverse Diagonal sum:',ld2_sum)
```

Comment: Why do you un-accept my answer, copy it, and then post it as your own?

Comment: Thank for your review. I accepted your answer now. But there are differences between your solution and mine. It was just the assignment of variables. But, yes I got the clue from your answer. Thanks again and sorry for not acknowledging earlier.

Comment: No worries, thanks. This can just be a bit frustrating sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Output1:
Enter number of rows   :5
Enter number of columns:4
The 2D Matrix is: 
[[10, 39, 40, 28],
 [35, 34, 14, 1],
 [27, 32, 20, 1],
 [11, 13, 13, 8],
 [28, 10, 16, 13]]
Row Sum             : [117, 84, 80, 45, 67]
Column sum          : [111, 128, 103, 51]
Please make sure that matrix is square
The diagonal sums are not possible

Output2:
Enter number of rows   :5
Enter number of columns:5
The 2D Matrix is: 
[[29, 16, 6, 48, 14],
 [18, 41, 4, 37, 4],
 [4, 41, 29, 44, 48],
 [19, 8, 46, 2, 50],
 [38, 49, 46, 1, 43]]
Row Sum             : [113, 104, 166, 125, 177]
Column sum          : [108, 155, 131, 132, 159]
Forward Diagonal sum: [144]
Reverse Diagonal sum: [126]
```